# Add description to an inherited field inside a pydantic object

Tags: python, enums, pydantic

I would like to add a custom description to an enum field. I tried the following code

```
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel


class BasicEnum(Enum):
    e1 = "E1"
    e2 = "E2"


class ModifiedEnum(BasicEnum):
    """
    This is really an enum!!!
    """


class PydandicObject(BaseModel):
    enum_field: ModifiedEnum
```

However, this returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp_enum.py", line 9, in <module>
    class ModifiedEnum(BasicEnum):
  File "C:\Users\lazlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\enum.py", line 146, in __prepare__
    metacls._check_for_existing_members(cls, bases)
  File "C:\Users\lazlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\enum.py", line 527, in _check_for_existing_members
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: ModifiedEnum: cannot extend enumeration 'BasicEnum'
```

Comment: Once an `enum` defines members (`e1` and `e2` in your `BasicEnum`) it cannot be subclassed.

Comment: Hey @EthanFurman, can I still modify or add a description?

Comment: You would have to do it manually, not via subclassing: `BasicEnum.e1.some_attr = 99`, for example.